# API catalogs - experience APIs vs system apis

Tags: integration, mulesoft, api-gateway, apigee

What are the security practices that differentiate system apis to experience APIs in API lex and layered API architecture

Answer (score 1):

The question is very open but I believe that the more important practice is usually that people want to ensure that System APIs to be called only by previous level APIs and not by users and clients.